# Round correct to 2 decimal places but if very close, set it to nearest integer

Tags: php, rounding, number-formatting

Is there any function or possibility where the number is round to a nearest integer value ONLY if the number is very close. Eg:

```
$var = 18.99;
$res = round($var, 2); // output: 18.99, expected - 19
```

I've tried with round without second param, but that will fail for 18.65.

```
$var = 18.99;
$res = round($var); //output - 19

$var = 18.65;
$res = round($var); //output - 19, expected 18.65
```

I just wanted the `.9` range to convert itselt to the next int value. Is this possible ?

Comment: What's the exact rounding rule you need? What if the number is 18.98 or 18.69?

Comment: No. There is not a built-in function that does exactly what you want for your specific use case. Is it possible to write your own. Of course.

Comment: 18.69 should be 18.69, but 18.98 should be 19. Basically all the .9 should be converted to the next int value

Comment: If all the X.9X should be converted to he next int value, you can do with regular expressions.

Comment: What is expected for `10.05`?

Comment: A value of 10. The accepted answer would return that too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This basically rounds any value to nearest integer and then checks the difference of the two with the limit.

```
function nearly_round($value, $limit = 0.1) { 
    $rounded = round($value); 
    //Check the difference. If less than the limit, 
    //return the rounded value, else the original number.
    return abs($rounded - $value) < $limit ? $rounded : $value; 
}

echo nearly_round(-0.9); // -1
echo nearly_round(-0.8); // -0.8
echo nearly_round(0.8);  // 0.8
echo nearly_round(0.9);  // 1
```